# how can i get unique wysihtml5-sandbox from textarea id.structure like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysihtml5

```
<textarea class="txtarea" name="abc" id="20">value of abc</textarea>
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox"></iframe>

<textarea class="txtarea" name="def" id="21">value of def</textarea>
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox"></iframe>

<textarea class="txtarea" name="ghi" id="22">value of ghi</textarea>
<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox"></iframe>

<input type="hidden" name="textedtor" id="textedtor" value="20,21,22">
```

when i press key on any editor field then get only and only his event

```
var field = jQuery("#textedtor").val();
var splitedfiled = field.split(',');
for(var m = 0;m<=splitedfiled.length;m++){
 if(splitedfiled[m]!=""){

    jQuery('#'+splitedfiled[m]).wysihtml5({
      events: {
        load: function() {
          jQuery('.wysihtml5-sandbox').contents().find('body').on("keydown",function(event) {
            alert(splitedfiled[m]);
          }); 
        }
      }
    });
 }
}
```

onkeyup event not work in textarea.

now it alert 3 time.because there are 3 id.i want to alert only 1 time.so,please help me

Comment: can you try with passing the id of the textarea inside the `on` event handler like `on("keydown",'#'+splitedfiled[m],function(event)`

Comment: it should be attached to the specified id only

Comment: i tried but not work